# PhP foreach loop for an XML file

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm trying to be able to get place as a variable to use on page.php. It will start to load options into the select box for about 5 seconds and I'll actually be able to see the options, then it all deletes and I have an empty select box. Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
echo '<form method="get" action="page.php"><select name="place" id="place">';
foreach($xml as $banana)
{
    if(isset($banana->id))
    {
        $id = $banana->id;
        $string = $banana->state . " - " . $banana->name;
        echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $string . '</option>';

    }
}
echo "</select>";
echo '<input type="submit" /></form>';

?>
```

I know for sure that my XML is formatted correctly, but the XML file has a little over 2500 entries that each looks something like this:

```
<container>
    <id>theId</id>
    <state>theState</state>
    <name>theName</name>
</container>
```

Any ideas why won't load?

Note: Some items have an empty id in the XML file, and I don't want to include those files, that's why I check to make sure it's set.

Comment: If instead of creating a select box you just `print_r($xml);` do all entries show?

Comment: @Ray Yes, they all show up with print_r($xml);

Comment: Also, if you're sticking data in HTML like that you're going to want to make it safe in case the id or name has characters that could mess up the HTML.   `echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($id) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($string) . '</option>';`

Comment: @Ray It's web safe in the XML file so I don't need to worry about that, all content is added to the XML file by me, not users. I really do appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: Do you have any Javascript binding on to the the select box? Disable javascript and refresh, does the pure html select box still die?

Comment: @Ray Also, I did add htmlspecialchars just to test it out, and i'm still hitting the same issue.

Comment: @Ray I disabled javascript and The select button worked, but I don't have any javascript that could be interfering with the select box. It has a unique id and nothing should be messing with it

Comment: @Ray I auto append a top layout page, and I actually do have a script that was trying to change the innerHTML of the id place. I forgot about it lol, thank you, it's working now.

Comment: Cool, will make that my official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things

- Disable any javascript and try again--something may be binding to overriding the select box or the id of an element in it.
- You generally want to properly escape text you pull in before inserting it into a HTML document in case there's a `<`, `>`, or such in it

Try the following:

```
   echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($id) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($string) . '</option>';
```